# How to avoid "Access is denied" error while accessing Process properties?

Tags: c#

I have a helper method in C# that tries to get object properties (like turning them into Dictionary object with key-value pair). It is similar to:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object?> GetPropertyValues(object obj, int currentLevel = 0, int maxLevel = 3)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object?> propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, object?>();
            if (currentLevel >= maxLevel)
            {
                propertyValues.Add("currentLevel", currentLevel);
                propertyValues.Add("maxLevel", maxLevel);
                return propertyValues;
            }
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object? value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (!value.GetType().IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        value = GetPropertyValues(value, ++currentLevel, maxLevel);
                    }
                }
                propertyValues.Add(name, value);
            }
            return propertyValues;
        }
```

but if I send and instance of a Process class then following line throws exception:

```
object? value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);
```

> Property accessor 'SafeHandle' on object 'System.Diagnostics.Process'
> threw the following exception:'Access is denied.'

I can also see Visual Studio debugger shows the same error;

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this error or skip properties if they will throw exception?
While I can cover the line with `try/catch` I am trying to find a native way to run execution without exception driven way.

Comment: In general, there is no way to ask "If I did this, *would* it throw an exception?" Even if there were, any answer you get would be obsolete once you get it, because the situation can change at any time. You can get the handle now, but 2 milliseconds later, you might not be able to.

Comment: Oh, hey Raymond! I am a big fan of you :) Anyways thanks for your comment. For some logging purposes I was trying to serialize Process object via JSON.NET but it was throwing same exception. So I tried to use this method but could not get around the problem. Then I don't see another way than wrapping that line around with `try/catch` and move on?